# gnome network manager: no internet, ping works, dig @8.8.8.8 works

Tags: gnome, opensuse

(also asked on StackOverflow, realized too late that is the wrong place).

Running opensuse tumbleweed with 4.7.5-1-default kernel and gnome.

Network managed with gnome's network-manager. Network (wired and wireless) connect to my router.

- `ping` works also to external IPs
- `dig` works if I provide the dns ip (eg. 8.8.8.8)
- `nmcli dev show | grep DNS` shows the right nameservers (which I set in the network managers interface): 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4, but `dig` without specification of the dns IP does not work
- `ping` etc. to internet names (e.g. google.com) does not work. Am completely lost by now. Help greatly appreciated.

Thank you, Axel

Comment: At home or enterprise?

Comment: home. Accessing the internet via a home network router.

Comment: Reboot your home router, it is not giving DNS properly or the DNS service is kaput.

Comment: Hi Rui, other laptops on the same network have no connection issues. They run opensuse with gnome, too, just an older version. Still think I should reboot the router? Thank you!

Comment: Missing default route? `ip route` `man ip;man ip-route`.

Comment: What is in your `/etc/resolved.conf` ?

Comment: /etc/resolve.conf = one line only "# Generated by NetworkManager".

Comment: ip route: "default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp4s0 proto static metric 600 192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp4s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.16 metric 600" with 192.168.1.1 being my router, 192.168.1.16 being the laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found on opensuse forum: the `/etc/resolve.conf` file was corrupted (empty). After deleting it and rebooting, the system (network-manager?) generated a new, working version. It contains the ip of the nameserver.